question on geometry of cyclic quadrilaterals
ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral. AB produced meets DC produced at F. AD produced
meets BC produced at E. Prove that the angle bisectors of ∠AEB and ∠AFD meet at right angles.
From the diagram we have to prove that ∠EGF = 90 .
I tried by making external angle equal to opposite interior angles. I found that ΔECD~ΔABE
and same for ΔFBC and ΔFAD and got that the ratio of sides is equal from that. But now i have no idea how to prove that the two angle bisectors are perpendicular.

This problem is also given and solved here

Another instance here

Set:
$$
\alpha=\angle BAD=\angle DCE=\angle BCF,
\quad
\beta=\angle ABC=\angle CDE.
$$
Then:
$$
\angle AFC=\beta-\alpha,
\quad
\angle AEC=\pi-\alpha-\beta.
$$
It follows that:
$$
\angle AFG+\angle AEG={\pi\over2}-\alpha
$$
and
$$
\angle EGF_{\text concave}=2\pi-\angle EAF-\angle AFG-\angle AEG
=3{\pi\over2}
$$

thanks bro, i should have stick to fundamental methods like angle chasing.
